# "Invalid volume specification: ':/var/lib/mysql'" when deploying multicontainer app with mysql to a web application

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a multicontainer app, which contains 2 images : one for my api, and one for a mysql database.

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
    restapi:
services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        image: <custom-image>:latest
        environment:
            ...
        depends_on:
            - mysql-server
        networks:
            - restapi
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
    mysql-server:
        container_name: mysql-server
        image: mysql:latest
        environment:
            ...
        networks:
            - restapi
        ports:
            - "8082:3306"
        volumes:
            -  ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

To deploy it, I created a webapp ressource, and configured it to compose this docker-compose file. When deploying it, I get the following error :

`2023-10-25T11:06:22.029Z ERROR - Container create failed for dockersqlapi_mysql-server_0_790d19a3 with System.AggregateException, One or more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid volume specification: ':/var/lib/mysql'"} ) InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"invalid volume specification: ':/var/lib/mysql'"}`

At first I thought it could be that ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} was not set, but it should still return '/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql' instead of ':/var/lib/mysql'.

Yet, here is my configuration :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqai1.png)

How is my volume specification invalid ? Do I need an additional resource ?

Thank you for your help, I will gladly give additional informations if needed, please let me know.

Comment: Unsupported options: 
Ports other than 80 and 8080 (ignored),
and depends_on (ignored),
networks (ignored),
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#unsupported-options

Just to highlight, the volumes option maps the file system to a directory within the container. ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} is an environment variable in App Service that is mapped to persistent storage for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Following-up from the comment.

Based on the docker compose file' info that you have shared, on multi-container app, the following' Docker Compose configuration options are unsupported.

-Ports other than 80 and 8080 (ignored),

-depends_on (ignored),

-networks (ignored),

Kindly check this Azure doc for more info: [Configure a custom container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options)

Just to highlight, the volumes option maps the file system to a directory within the container. ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} is an environment variable in App Service that is mapped to persistent storage for your app.

You may leverage sample outlined in this doc: [Create a multi-container (preview) app using a Docker Compose configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container#download-the-sample)